# Open chat page with a contact on Kik programmatically

Tags: java, android, kik

I have a list of phone contacts in my android app, I want to open chat with a contact if the user taps on it. I can open profile page of a user with the following code:

```
  KikClient.getInstance().openProfileForKikUsername(this, "username");
```

But I can't always know the username of a Kik contact. I couldn't find anything helpful on Kik API GitHub page either. Thank you.

Comment: If you don't know the username how will you open the profile?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. @Rab
I know the phone number of the user. The goal is to get the list of contacts from Kik and display them. If user taps on the contact, my app should open up the chat page with that contact on Kik.

Comment: I don't believe Kik has an API to get username from phone numbers.

Comment: I just thought there might be a way to accomplish this.